# how to create users and associate roles and provide authentication to the roles

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, authentication, forms-authentication

i am developing an application in mvc3 and i need to provide authentication to my views.
I want to create 2 roles like "Admin","Users"
and then add users to the respective roles.
Authentication to be provided is like when the user logged in his role is checked and accordingly a view is shown to him.
I need to create two different views for each role..
I am completely new to this part of MVC.

I searched for this a lot but what i found was only part of code.Not even one could explain me step by step hw to go about it..
please if any1 can show me simple demo of how to do or u can suggest me any tutorial that i should follow..
Please Help...

Answer (score 0):

the MSDN article on Role Providers is pretty good... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647401.aspx... Step 4 really goes into the meat of how you assign roles to a person and how you check their role... I hope this helps!